# Laravel routing with virtual sub-domain name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am making one application where some routes should act like they are routing from sub domain.

NB : I don't want to create sub domains. Everything will work from the controllers and routes.

This is the url

```
http://myapp.com/site/Home
```

This is the route

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{site}.myapp.com'], function () {
   Route::get('/{site}/{page}', 'page@site');

});
```

I am trying to make the url look like

```
http://site.myapp.com/Home
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve this one ?

Comment: You current setup will force you to call  http://site.myapp.com/site/Home you basically have the  site parameter twice. Just remove the {site} for your inner route. The page@site should still be aware of the site parameter

Comment: I don't have to create sub domain right ?

Comment: You will ofcourse need a subdomain wildcard to get this working. Your sever is not aware of your laravel implementation. You basically define that *.mysite.com points to your public folder

Comment: @FrankProvost - I have created a sub domain. Now I am routing the staff like this...

`Route::group(['domain' => '{site}.myapp.com'], function () {
   Route::get('/{page}', 'page@site');

});`

But it is showing 404 error. My sub domain has nothing inside of it. Whatever code is written everything is in my main domain. As I asked before. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: So you created a subdomain on your webserver and made it point to your public laravel - app folder? If yes - then your given route should be called. Give an example for your subdomain. Where does it point to? What happens if you call it directly wihtout /{page}?

Comment: I transfered  everything to root from the public folder. 
Route::group(['domain' => '{site}.myapp.com'], function ()
 { Route::get('/{page}', 'page@site'); });
I am sending {site} and {page} to page controller's site method to show all the data respect to these two parameter.

Before it was like

Route::get('/{site}/{page}', 'page@site');

it is working fine. I seriously dont know what to do after this. I am not getting any help online .

Comment: What is "I transfered everything to root from the public folder" supposed to mean? Please elaborate on what you did to create a subdomain. Is it a wildcard? a specfic one? Where does it point to?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one chance to have a graceful way of doing what you try to do. You need a so called subdomain wildcard. That means that your hoster gives you the option to define *.mydomain.tdl as a subdomain.

This subdomain needs to point to exactly the same folder as your mydomain.tdl - so the public folder of your app. Do not change anything else.

Finally define a group to fetch all subdomains as parameter

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{user}.mydomain.tdl'], function()
{
     Route::get('{site}', 'MyController@DoStuff');
}
```

For Testing Purposes you can simply also define a second generic route outside the group

```
Route::get('{user}/{site}', 'MyController@DoStuff');
```

Now you have to options to access the page

- username.mydomain.tdl/sitename
- mydomain.tdl/username/sitename

Be aware of the following: www is a subdomain too if you define a wildcard. Therefore www will start matching your defiend subdomain.

Another important detail is that you will have a hard time to get this running on localhost. If you are not sure about wildcards just define a specfic new subdomain that will also match the group

example.myDomain.tdl could point to the laravel - app public folder (just like myDomain.tdl) and should than pass example as parameter for your defined route